# How do i make the form field responsive?

Tags: html, css, django, responsive-design, django-crispy-forms

I have just started to learn django few weeks. To learn more effectively i have started to build a hotel website and deployed using heroku. The website seems better on mine laptop but looks worse on my ipad or mobile. I wanted to make the form fields reponsive using css or django crispy form. I have found a lot of answers but none of them help me understand how to do it. Also any further recommendation for the website would be recommended for me as a beginner in web development.
Here is the website: https://hotel-jumera.herokuapp.com
(Its mine practise for building website, so sorry for in case copyright issue)
form field in template:

```
<form  method='post'>
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{booking_form.as_p }}
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success"> Send </button>
</form>
```

Comment: You can use bootstrap

Comment: using bootstrap's `class = "form-control"` on your form fields might be enough after checking your website...

Comment: Sorry to bother you but i am unable to  use class="form-control", i tried to research  on it , but it just seems so vague for me.Thanks!

Comment: Can you be more specific on how to use the class="form-control " on the form

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is set some break points in your css where you can change the width of elements on your site

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 400px) {
  .col-2 {
      background-color: red;
  }
}
```

If the browser window is 600px or bigger, the background color will be red.
This is a mobile first approach. You build your site for mobile and then add breakpoints to cater for larger screens `tablet min-width: 600px` and `desktop min-width: 1200px`

Comment: I tried to use media queries but it seems it doesnot have any effect to my browser.Thanks!

Comment: I'm going to need more info
Where are you added the media query

Comment: I have tried every where and finally got  somewhat reponsive but using django-crispy-forms